# Visual Studio Code - icons in Activity Bar have disappeared

Tags: visual-studio-code

Earlier this week I installed the latest release (May 2018) of Visual Studio Code and ever since then all the icons in the Activity Bar (i.e. the long thin bar on the far left of the window) fail to display. I always get the Explorer icon but after that the only one that *does* display is whatever I currently have open in the sidebar.
Perhaps some screenshots might help explain:
[image]
[image]
[image]

I've searched high and low in Settings to try and find how to get them all to display but I can't find anything. Can anyone help?

I'm on macOS High Sierra 10.13.5 by the way.

Comment: Have you verified that your Preference Settings?  That you still have the same icon template/extension selected.  In the past I've run into having my selection reset on update.

Comment: Or Click the Gear Icon and see the Icon Theme

Comment: I do still have the same File Icon Theme (i.e. Seti) selected. I doubt that affects what shows up in the Activity Bar though?

Comment: I apologize I assumed it was just the icons.

Comment: Try right clicking the Activity Bar itself.  If I right click it I get a list of the icons to show/hide.  Showing there is a checkbox, otherwise it's hidden

Comment: You can hit Ctrl + Shift + E to show Explorer, Ctrl + Shift + D to show debugger

Comment: "Try right clicking the Activity Bar itself. If I right click it I get a list of the icons to show/hide." That did it :) Thx @DylanWright

Comment: No problem glad I could help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Try right clicking the Activity Bar itself. If I right click it I get a list of the icons to show/hide."

Answer (score 15):

Right click on the activity bar itself and select whatever you want have on the activity side bar. if for some reason you don't see the activity bar, go to 
**View-> Appearance ->Show Activity bar**

[image]

Comment: I was looking for how to show the Activity Bar, as I'd accidentally hidden it. So +1 from me

Answer (score 7):

In VSCode version 1.59 (Windows 10), the setting of controlling the visibility of activity bar is:

Settings -> User >-> Workbench -> Appearance -> Activity Bar -> "Visible
Controls the visibility of the activity bar in the workbench"

See the screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is the only fix that worked for me on Mac:

Click "View" > "Open view...". Search for the extension. From there you can open the extension in a side panel.

Answer (score 0):

Click on menu, if you don't have the top menu click the alt key the menu will appear. On the menu click view then click appearance, then click show activity bar. If all the activity bar does not show, go back to view menu to bring them back one by one. To keep an icon from disappearing right click on each activity bar, look for keep, click it. That will make it stay.

Answer (score 0):

If you are a windows user and have the latest version of visual studio code
1)First go to the view section in the upper top of the visual studio code.
2)GO to preferences
3)Go to show Activity Bar and click on it.

Answer (score 0):

This is what worked for me

View -> Appearance -> Activity Bar Position -> Side

[image]

Comment: changing its location doesn't make it disappear...