# VsCode: Explorer on activity bar not showing

Tags: visual-studio-code

I can't see anymore the explorer on my activity bar on vsCode. I used to have a file icon  that enables me to navigate through files of the project but I don't see it anymore and i can't find a way to put it back.

[image: issue_vscode]

I did try to follow: [Visual Studio Code - icons in Activity Bar have disappeared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50857771/visual-studio-code-icons-in-activity-bar-have-disappeared#:%7E:text=Click%20on%20menu%2C%20if%20you,them%20back%20one%20by%20one.)

But the explorer feature does not show when I right click on activity bar:
[image: explorer not showing]

I have a mac, so i tried the short cut: `cmd + shift + E`. But it does not work as well.

When I go to `Settings -> User >-> Workbench -> Appearance -> Activity Bar`:
[image: user settings]

**How can I see the explorer in my activity bar again ?**

Comment: can you check if https://stackoverflow.com/q/76144000/11107541 helps you?

Comment: It worked using 'the nuclear option': `View: Reset View Locations`. Thank you !

Comment: could you consider voting on the answers there? see also [/help/why-vote](/help/why-vote)

Answer (score 0):

Go to View on menu bar on the top, then select explorer from options

Comment: I don't have an "options" or "explorer" field when i go on view.

Comment: Ok, so maybe try ctrl+shift+E